# Почему не срабатывает замена числа на слово?

Tags: javascript, циклы, switch

Почему не срабатывает замена числа на слово? В консоль выводится только числа от 1 до 100.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  switch (i) {
    case ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0)):
      console.log("трипять");
      break;
    case (i % 3 == 0):
      console.log("три");
      break;
    case (i % 5 == 0):
      console.log("пять");
      break;
    default:
      console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: default срабатывает

Comment: Потому что switch-case работает не так, замените его на if-else

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/switch

Comment: c if else я сделал - все прекрасно работает, но мне интересно как решить данную задачу при помощи swith

Comment: Статью на learn.javascript.ru/switch я тоже читал. У меня что-то не так  записано или в принципе так делать нельзя и при помощи switch данную задачу решить не получится?

Answer (score 5):

Потому что проверять надо не значение i, а истинность выражения в case - т.е. не switch(i), а switch(true):

```js
for(var i=1; i<=100; i++){
    switch(true){
        case ((i%3 == 0)&&(i%5 == 0)):
            console.log("трипять");
            break;
        case (i%3 == 0):
            console.log("три");     
            break; 
        case (i%5 == 0):
            console.log("пять");
            break;
        default:
            console.log(i); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`switch` сравнивает значение переменной со значениями указанными в блоках `case`. И когда эти два значения совпадают, выполняет этот блок.

В `case` у вас вычисляются логические значения. И вы ожидаете, что будет выполняться блок со значением `true`. Значит именно это значение нужно поставить в оператор `switch`

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  switch (true) {
    case ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0)):
      console.log("трипять");
      break;
    case (i % 3 == 0):
      console.log("три");
      break;
    case (i % 5 == 0):
      console.log("пять");
      break;
    default:
      console.log(i);
  }
}
```

А вообще код

```
switch (x) {
  case a: doA(); break;
  case b: doB(); break;
  default: doDef();
}
```

Переписывается в такой

```
if (x == a)
  doA();
else if (x == b)
  doA();
else
  doDef();
```

Или для вашего случая

```
if (i == ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0)))
  console.log("трипять");
else if (i == (i % 3 == 0))
  console.log("три");
else if (i == (i % 5 == 0))
  console.log("пять");
else
  console.log(i);
```

И тогда понятно, почему ваш код не работает